# Linux as 3rd boot OS

Tags: linux, linux-mint, boot, grub2, swap

I would like to install another linux kali beside my linux mint and win10.
My question is, do I need make 3 partition again for installation, /root /home and swap od I don't need swap because I already have it from the Mint.

And what about the boot loader (GRUB2 whatever) since I already installed it once.
Can I skip that installation or what?

I want to hear your opinions and try to find best option.

Comment: Kali isn't meant for daily use. You could run it within virtualbox instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, you don't need to have three partitions.  You didn't even need them for the Mint install - they're a choice, not a requirement.  You could have 1 big `/` partition, or multiple small partitions, or anything in between.  As long as `/bin`, `/lib`, `/etc`, and `/sbin` are on the rootfs, it will be fine.

IIRC, `systemd` chokes if `/usr` isn't on the rootfs too. because LP knows best and "nobody needs to do that any more"...so if you're running `systemd` or are likely to get force-migrated to systemd in future, don't do that.

2. yes, you can share the swap partition with Mint unless you are using it for suspend-to-disk aka hibernate.
3. you won't need to install grub into the MBR again, but you will need to update your grub configuration to generate a menu that includes your new kali installation.  The easiest way to do that is to let the kali installer install grub again.  Otherwise, make sure you have the grub packages AND the `os-prober` package installed and run `update-grub`